# Get all customers who have multiple specific values in a column

Tags: pandas, filter

How can I do this?:

Get all customers who have given both the first name (name_fist) and the birthday.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'customer_ID': ['a','a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
     'parameter': ['name_fist', 'name_last', 'birthday', 'name_fist', 
                   'name_fist', 'name_last', 'birthday', 'name_fist', 'name_last']})

customer_ID   parameter
0   a    name_fist
1   a    name_last
2   a    birthday
3   b    name_fist
4   c    name_fist
5   c    name_last
6   c    birthday
7   d    name_fist
8   d    name_last
```

The answer should be "2".

Ideally, I get the customer ID for all people where this condition is true: a and c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
(df.query('parameter in ["name_fist", "birthday"]')\
   .groupby('customer_ID')['parameter'].nunique() == 2)
```

Output:

```
customer_ID
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
Name: parameter, dtype: bool
```

***Details:***

Filter the dataframe first for the parameters of interest using `query`, then `groupby` and use `nunique` to count the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `groupby` customer_ID and then check by `set.issuperset` (note that you have a typo of "name_fist" instead of "first":

```
print (df.groupby("customer_ID")["parameter"]
       .apply(lambda d: set(d).issuperset({"name_fist","birthday"})))

#
customer_ID
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
Name: parameter, dtype: bool
```